# How to create a dynamic in-clause where clause for a uniqueidentifier column in EF Core for SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a table that has a column called `UserGuid` that is of type `uniqueidentifier`.

I want to use [Dynamic Linq](https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core).

I can easily search for one value:

```
    var filterClause = $"UserGuid.Equals(@0)";
    items = items.Where(filterClause, value);
```

But when I try to search for a list of values (similar to `in` clause of T-SQL), it throws an error.

My code is:

```
var whereCluase = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
{
    if (i > 0)
    {
        whereCluase += " OR ";
    }
    whereCluase += ("UserGuid.Contains(@" + i + ")");
}
items = items.Where(whereCluase, values.ToArray());
```

And I see this error:

> No applicable method 'Contains' exists in type 'Guid'

How can I solve this? How can I have `in` clause in dynamic LINQ for GUID columns?

Comment: There's no `.Equals` or any kind of method in SQL. If you want to generate an `IN` clause, you do it the same way for all types. `Where(item=>ids.Contains(item.Id))`. This generates the clause you want: `id in (@id1,@id2,@id3,...)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, are you familiar with dynamic LINQ? Because the first code works. `.Equals` works.

Comment: Yes I am, since it came out. It's a quirky way to write what you can't do in LINQ that never caught on, then was taken over by a company that makes it a habit to hijack names that don't belong to it. And has switched its products to closed-source/for-pay at least once in the past. Dynamic LINQ still produces a LINQ query. You don't need it to generate an `IN` clause. There's a reason Dynamic LINQ never caught on though.  LINQ is *already* dynamic in most cases. The Fluent API already combines operators to generate queries dynamically. In other cases people mainly use LinqKit

Comment: You can generate an OR clause dynamically without giving up LINQ's type safety (its main advantage) by using LINQKit's PredicateBuilder. [The landing page example](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit#more-examples) builds an OR expression in a loop, without using any strings.

Comment: Really this should go through a Table Valued Parameter. But Entity Framework doesn't support them. You could write a function or stored procedure that uses oone, and then map it using `FromSqlRaw`